# Pyspark: save transformers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using some transformers of Pyspark such as StringIndexer, StandardScaler and more. I first apply those to the training set and then later on I want to use the same transformation objects (same parameters of StringIndexerModel, StandardScalerModel) in order to apply them on the test set. Therefore, I am looking for a way to save those transformation functions as a file. However, I cannot find any related method but only with ml functions such as LogisticRegression. Do you know any possible way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify if you work with MLlib or ML?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I am working with pyspark.ml.

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy  solution.

Save the indexer model to a file (on HDFS).

```
writer = indexerModel._call_java("write")
writer.save("indexerModel")
```

Load the indexer model from a file (saved on HDFS).

```
indexer = StringIndexerModel._new_java_obj("org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel.load", "indexerModel")
indexerModel = StringIndexerModel(indexer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of StringIndexer and StandardScaler are both RDDs, so you can either save the models directly to a file or, more likely what you want, you can persist the results for later computation.

To save to a parquet file call (you might need a schema attached as well) `sqlContext.createDataFrame(string_indexed_rdd).write.parquet("indexer.parquet")`. You would then need to program loading this result back from a file when you wanted it.

To persist call `string_indexed_rdd.persist()`. This will save the intermediary results in memory for reuse later. You can pass options to save to disk as well if you are memory limited.

---

If you want to just persist the model itself, you're stuck on an existing bug/missing capability in the api ([PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10419)). If the underlying issue was resolved and didn't provide new methods, you need to call some underlying methods manually to get and set the model parameters. Looking through the model code you can see that the Models inherit from a chain of classes, one of which is `Params`. This class has the `extractParamMap` which pulls out the parameters used in the model. You can then save this in any manner you wish for persisting python dicts. Then you need to create an empty model object and follow that with a call to `copy(saved_params)` to pass the persisted parameters into the object.

Something along these lines should work:

```
def save_params(model, filename):
    d = shelve.open(filename)
    try:
        return d.update(model.extractParamMap())
    finally:
        d.close()

def load_params(ModelClass, filename):
    d = shelve.open(filename)
    try:
        return ModelClass().copy(dict(d))
    finally:
        d.close()
```

Comment: I'm not interested in saving the transformed data but the model itself. For example, I would like to save the StandardScalerModel which is not a RDD.

Comment: Ahh your question wasn't clear on that point -- I scanned through the source code and added what I think will achieve what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work because no parameters are included in the param map.If I just check in  the instance of my StringIndexerModel it just returns an empty array ([]).

Comment: Hmm well without code or a debugable instance of my own to mess with it's hard to say what's wrong. What version of spark are you on? I'm reading 1.6 source code. Those models don't inherit from `MLWritable` so there's no native method to call currently. Try testing `_transfer_params_from_java` followed by a print of `self._paramMap` before you save -- make sure there's something there. Then try explicitly calling `_transfer_params_to_java` after setting the `self._paramMap`. These bypass the methods. Beyond that you'd need to explore the implementation code in spark and your repo.

Comment: I did look up at the source code and tried out what you just described. Apparently, there is already a pull request about it: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10419

Comment: Ahhh, good find -- yea seems like a bug in the model implementation on top of the lacking export feature.